# count amount of "PAP" substring appearances in O(n)

Tags: node.js

Hi i've been struggling with this problem for a bit I need to count the amount of "PAP" substrings in a word, where the letters don't have to be consecutive.

Best I demonstrate by example.

For example:
The substring "PAPAPYSYIOIWIN" I need to return 4.

- **PAP**APYSYIOIWIN
- **PA**PA**P**YSYIOIWIN
- **P**AP**AP**YSYIOIWIN
- PA**PAP**YSYIOIWIN

I need to solve this in O(n) but so far have only got an O(n^3) solution by doing something like this:

```js
let count = 0
for (let c of word) {

    for (let d of word) {

        for (let e of word) {
            if(c === 'P' && d === 'A' && 'e' === 'P')
            count ++;
        }
    }
}
return count
```

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a O(n) solution:

```js
console.log(getPAP("PAPAPYSYIOIWIN"))
function getPAP(str) {
    let p1 = 0, p2 = 0
    let res = 0
    for (let char of str) {
        if (char === 'P')
            p1++;
    }

    for (let char of str) {
        if (char === 'P') {
            p2++;
            p1--;
        }
        else if (char === 'A')
            res += p1 * p2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Explanation**:

p1 is the amount of P's before an A and p2 is the amount of P's after an A and then for each A there are p1*p2 possible ways of making the word PAP.

Comment: Testing this now